# How to encrypt my files so that it cannot be accessed from live USB?

Tags: password

I thought that when i have my password set, nobody could access my files. Turns out I was wrong. I plugged USB with live system image and without entering any password I could read all files from my main hard drive. I guess it works the same when someone connects through wifi to my laptop.
How do I set the password so nobody can read my files?

Comment: Everybody with physical access to your computer can read (and manipulate) the files on your hard drive unless you encrypt them. You can choose to encrypt your home folder during installation of Ubuntu. By the way, "connecting through wifi" should not be a problem because in that case you usually connect to the running operating system which will deny access unless you provide the correct password.